# Fixing Load denied by X-Frame options when trying to load new iframe url and text

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

I have a page on my site where I have an iframe large video displayed, and below it, 3 columns of thumbnail/title/time of my other youtube videos. I want to have it so when a user clicks the thumbnail, the title above the main video changes along with the new video loaded in the same iframe window. Right now I think I have it correct but I understand this is a security issue and as a result the iframe won't load the new videos. What is a way I can make this work so that it's secure and works? I get the error **Load denied by X-Frame-Options**

```
<h2>Video Gallery</h2>
<p id = "description"></p>

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 mbl">
    <iframe name ="mainframe" class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ZuGHts631vM" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


<article class="video">
    <figure>
        <a target="mainframe" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/"><img onclick="myFunction('How to ....')" class="videoThumb" src="../../images/thumbnails/thumb1.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
    <h3 class="videoTitle">How to ....</h3>
    <p class ="time">0:31</p>

</article>

<article class="video">
    <figure>
        <a target="mainframe" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img onclick="myFunction('funny video')" class="videoThumb" src="../../images/thumbnails/thumb2.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
    <h3 class="videoTitle">Funny video</h3>
    <p class ="time">1:59</p>

</article>

<article class="video">
    <figure>
        <a target="mainframe" href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img onclick="myFunction('Crazy Jump')" class="videoThumb" src="../../images/thumbnails/thumb3.jpg"></a>
    </figure>
    <h3 class="videoTitle">Crazy Jump</h3>
    <p class ="time">1:29</p>

</article>


<script>
function myFunction(name)
{
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML =  "" + name;

}
</script>
```

Comment: how do you do that, and is this standard practice? I feel like there has to be a better way to do this and avoid any security issues.

Comment: you can't just frame other people's stuff like that. youtube is nice enough to provide embed code and even a player API, and those will not only work on your site, they will work out much better for your users than iframing...

Comment: I was thinkin about that...I might try that out

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using the embedded link for the  youtube video, I was just copying the URL of the video at the top :/ Fixed